# Unable to Find Issue in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a database with three tables. The first two tables work just fine. My third table seems to be adding data (Strings fine to the Database. I opened up database in a viewer and all columns were in place with values i entered.

I get the problem when displaying this info in a Recycleradapter in ActivityInvoice. App shuts down. Maybe I'm missing something minuscule that someone else might see.

I can get the activity to load with no data if I comment out getAllInvoices called in InvoiceActivity.

Here is InvoiceActivity (Should show info in recyclerview)

```
package com.nuclient.travisbunn.nuclient;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InvoiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private AppCompatActivity activity = InvoiceActivity.this;
private RecyclerView recyclerViewInvoices;
private List<Invoice> listInvoices;
private InvoiceRecyclerAdapter invoiceRecyclerAdapter;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private FloatingActionButton myFab;
private FloatingActionButton myBack;
private FloatingActionButton myEdit;
private FloatingActionButton mySub;
private Invoice invoice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_invoice);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Invoices");
    initViews();
    initObjects();
    initListeners();
}


// Update recyclerView onResume of activity
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getDataFromSQLite();
}


/**
 * This method is to initialize views
 */
private void initViews() {
    recyclerViewInvoices = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewInvoices);
}

/**
 * This method is to initialize listeners
 */
private void initListeners(){
    myFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addButtonTwo);
    myBack = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.backButtonTwo);
    myEdit = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.editButtonTwo);
    mySub = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.minusButtonTwo);
    myFab.setOnClickListener(this);
    myBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    myEdit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mySub.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/**
 * This method is to initialize objects to be used
 */
private void initObjects() {
    listInvoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
    invoiceRecyclerAdapter = new InvoiceRecyclerAdapter(listInvoices);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewInvoices.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewInvoices.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewInvoices.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewInvoices.setAdapter(invoiceRecyclerAdapter);

    invoice = new Invoice();
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);

    getDataFromSQLite();
}



/**
 * This method is to fetch all invoice records from SQLite
 */

private void getDataFromSQLite() {
    // AsyncTask is used that SQLite operation not blocks the UI Thread.
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            listInvoices.clear();
            listInvoices.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllInvoices());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            invoiceRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }.execute();
}



// Method that enables the buttons on bottom
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.addButtonTwo:
            Intent intentAddInvoice = new Intent(this, AddInvoiceActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intentAddInvoice, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.editButtonTwo:
            //editChecked();
            break;
        case R.id.minusButtonTwo:
            /*
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener);
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
            */
            break;
        case R.id.backButtonTwo:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my invoiceRecyclerAdapter:

```
package com.nuclient.travisbunn.nuclient;

import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.List;


public class InvoiceRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InvoiceRecyclerAdapter.InvoiceViewHolder> {


private List<Invoice> listInvoices;

public InvoiceRecyclerAdapter(List<Invoice> listInvoices) {
    this.listInvoices = listInvoices;
}

@Override
public InvoiceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // inflating recycler item view
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_invoice_recycler, parent, false);
    return new InvoiceViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(InvoiceRecyclerAdapter.InvoiceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final int pos = position;

    holder.textViewName.setText(listInvoices.get(position).getName());
    holder.textViewDate.setText(listInvoices.get(position).getDate());
    holder.textViewTime.setText(listInvoices.get(position).getTime());
    holder.textViewMoney.setText(listInvoices.get(position).getMoney());
    holder.textViewRate.setText(listInvoices.get(position).getRate());


    /*
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(listClients.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.checkBox.setTag(listClients.get(position));

    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            Client contact = (Client) cb.getTag();

            contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
            listClients.get(pos).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
        }
    });
    */

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.v(InvoiceRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(),""+listInvoices.size());
    return listInvoices.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


/**
 * ViewHolder class
 */
public class InvoiceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public AppCompatTextView textViewName;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewDate;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewTime;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewMoney;
    public AppCompatTextView textViewRate;

    //public AppCompatCheckBox checkBox;

    public InvoiceViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textViewName = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewInvoiceName);
        textViewDate = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewInvoiceDate);
        textViewTime = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewInvoiceTime);
        textViewMoney = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewInvoiceMoney);
        textViewRate = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewInvoiceRate);
        //checkBox = (AppCompatCheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}

}
```

Here is my DatabaseHelper (limited to Invoice table for space):

```
package com.nuclient.travisbunn.nuclient;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Manager.db";

/*
 *
 * Beginning of INVOICE Table
 *
 */
// User table name
private static final String TABLE_INVOICE = "invoice";

// User Table Columns names
private static final String COLUMN_INVOICE_ID = "invoice_id";
private static final String COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME = "invoice_name";
private static final String COLUMN_INVOICE_DATE = "invoice_date";
private static final String COLUMN_INVOICE_TIME = "invoice_time";
private static final String COLUMN_INVOICE_MONEY = "invoice_money";
private static final String COLUMN_INVOICE_RATE = "invoice_rate";

// create table sql query
private String CREATE_INVOICE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INVOICE + "("
        + COLUMN_INVOICE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_INVOICE_DATE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_INVOICE_TIME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_INVOICE_MONEY + " TEXT," + COLUMN_INVOICE_RATE + " TEXT" +")";

// drop table sql query
private String DROP_INVOICE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INVOICE;

/*
 *
 * End of INVOICE Table
 *
 */

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CLIENT_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_INVOICE_TABLE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop User Table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

    //Drop Client table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_CLIENT_TABLE);

    //Drop Invoice table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_INVOICE_TABLE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

/*
 *
 *Start of INVOICE methods
 *
 */

/**
 * This method is to create invoice record
 */
public void addInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME, invoice.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_DATE, invoice.getDate());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_TIME, invoice.getTime());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_MONEY, invoice.getMoney());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_RATE, invoice.getRate());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_INVOICE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

/**
 * This method is to fetch all invoice and return the list of client records
 *
 * @return list
 */
public List<Invoice> getAllInvoices() {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_INVOICE_ID,
            COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME,
            COLUMN_INVOICE_DATE,
            COLUMN_INVOICE_TIME,
            COLUMN_INVOICE_MONEY,
            COLUMN_INVOICE_RATE
    };

    // sorting orders
    String sortOrder =
            COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME + " ASC";


    List<Invoice> invoiceList = new ArrayList<Invoice>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // query the client table
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INVOICE, //Table to query
            columns,    //columns to return
            null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
            null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,       //filter by row groups
            sortOrder); //The sort order

    // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
            invoice.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INVOICE_ID))));
            invoice.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME)));
            invoice.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INVOICE_DATE)));
            invoice.setTime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INVOICE_TIME)));
            invoice.setMoney(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INVOICE_MONEY)));
            invoice.setRate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_INVOICE_RATE)));
            // Adding client record to list
            invoiceList.add(invoice);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    db.close();

    // return client list
    return invoiceList;

}

/**
 * This method to update invoice record
 *
 * @param invoice
 */
public void updateInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME, invoice.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_DATE, invoice.getDate());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_TIME, invoice.getTime());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_MONEY, invoice.getMoney());
    values.put(COLUMN_INVOICE_RATE, invoice.getRate());

    // updating row
    db.update(TABLE_INVOICE, values, COLUMN_INVOICE_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(invoice.getId())});
    db.close();
}

/**
 * This method is to delete invoice record
 *
 * @param invoice
 */
public void deleteInvoice(Invoice invoice) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // delete invoice record by id
    db.delete(TABLE_INVOICE, COLUMN_INVOICE_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(invoice.getId())});
    db.close();
}

/**
 * This method to check client exist or not
 *
 */
public boolean checkInvoice(String email) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_INVOICE_ID
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection = COLUMN_INVOICE_NAME + " = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {email};

    // query client table with condition

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INVOICE, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return cursorCount > 0;

}

/*
 *
 *End of INVOICE methods
 *
 */
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Please post your logcat.

Comment: 04-18 00:24:09.546 6824-6824/com.nuclient.travisbunn.nuclient E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: 

com.nuclient.travisbunn.nuclient, PID: 6824

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #168: Error inflating class <unknown>

lots more about inflator and recycleradapter after that...looking into the inflater now to see if I can find anything... @Henry

Comment: Check if you made a mistake in one of your layout files.

Comment: Yup....had two buttons in there that I wasn't actually declaring or using...worked when taken out. Probably will work when I declare them.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this. Thank you @Henry for pointing out the logcat (sort of new so when you asked I immediately figured out how). Turns out in my recycler adapter I had two floating buttons. Taking them out solved the problem. I will have to put them back in (and hopefully it works) but it is likely because I never declared them I just had them sitting there temporarily.